# Add together 2 form inputs

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to take the input of firstName and lastName and console log it. I know I can then add that into a box and that part works when I add it. However I can never get the values of the boxes to show up or add.

I am getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Basically it's simple addition but getting the value is where I am getting the issue.

```js
function addNames() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstName").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("lastName").value);
  var answer = document.getElementById("answer");
  answer.value = a + b;
}

addNames();
```

```css
body {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

h1 {
  color: #bdbdbd;
  font-weight: 300;
}

form {
  color: white;
}

h2 {
  color: #bdbdbd;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="title"> Fill Out Form With Your Name</h1>
  <form>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstName" value=""><br> Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastName" value="">
  </form>
  <button onclick="addNames()"> Click Here</button>
  <h2 id="result"></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's your element with the ID of `answer`?

Comment: You're trying to convert names to integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among other issues, you don't add strings, you concatenate them. You also don't convert them to integers. Fortunately with JavaScript being loosely-typed you can use the addition operator to combine them:

```
var a = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
var b = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
var c = a + b;
```

Of course you probably want a space in there:

```
var c = a + ' ' + b;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to execute addNames() only on button click.
2. The h2 inside which you're trying to show the added numbers is not referenced properly. You need to do `document.getElementById("result")` and set the innerHTML.

```js
function addNames() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstName").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("lastName").value);
  var answer = a + b;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = answer;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

h1 {
  color: #bdbdbd;
  font-weight: 300;
}

form {
  color: white;
}

h2 {
  color: #bdbdbd;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="title"> Fill Out Form With Your Name</h1>
  <form>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstName" value=""><br> Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastName" value="">
  </form>
  <button onclick="addNames()"> Click Here</button>
  <h2 id="result"></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have 2 issues.

1. The first is the function call to `addNames()` in your script. Remove that since it's blowing up on pageload.
2. The second looks like your js you are looking for id `answer` but your html you have id `result`

And

3. You don't need to convert the values to integers to add them like others have said